# querying and deleting a chat inbox system using cassandara

Tags: database, cassandra

I'm making a chat application using Cassandra. I have a table called "chats" where I store the chatid,userid and timestamp. I have another table where I store the messages . (chatid , messageid,message).  When ever a new message comes in for a chatid I want to update the timestamp value in the "chats" table for that chatid. I want to use    CLUSTERING ORDER BY on the timestamp col. When a user needs to get all of their chats I query this table using userid to get all the chats in order by timestamp. The problem i'm having is I'm not able to delete a row form the "chats" table using userid and chatid. If I make userid and chatid Primary key I am not able to use just the userid to get the all chats for a user. How can I go about solving my problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the exact schema for your tables as well as your failing delete statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table chats:

You should create userid as Partition key. chatid & timestamp should be clustering column.
Please see below schema:

```
CREATE TABLE chats (    
    userid text,
    chatid text,
    timestamp timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((userid), chatid, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (userid ASC, timestamp DESC );
```

Now you can only delete by userid, ALso If you want to delete a particular chat you must be knowing user of that chat. so you can put both while deleting by chatid.

Now If you want to use CLUSTERING ORDER BY on the timestamp col then it must be a clustering column as created above.

In case you only want to update timestamp in a row is not possible directly, As it will insert a new row. So you need to manage your code by:

First select by userid & chatid.
if exists then delete it & insert a new entry with updated timestamp.